# Авторитетні джерела правил української мови

Tags: discussion

Які джерела/ресурси правил української мови можна використовувати для пошуку відповідей, коли виникають питання з української мови.
На які ресурси найкраще посилатися при пошуку відповіді на питання з ukrainian.stackexchange

Comment: Вас може зацікавити це питання: http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/8/%d0%94%d0%b5%d1%8f%d0%ba%d1%96-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bd%d1%96-%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd-%d0%b4%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0-some-useful-online-sources